# Setting up ADFS for a Web App

Tags: azure, web-applications, single-sign-on, adfs

Following scenario:
I have a web app running in the MS Azure cloud
The app provides a user logon with username and password
The new requirement is to provide the AD FS SSO for the web app, so that once a user has logged on the Windows machine, her AD credentials can be used to log on the web app.

Can anyone help with some background information and step-by-step instruction. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes - you can do this by federating [ADFS and Azure AD](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/connect/active-directory-aadconnectfed-whatis).

That provides SSO and lets the users authenticate on the intranet.

Do you have to use ADFS? If not, [pass-through](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/connect/active-directory-aadconnect-pass-through-authentication) is a good alternative.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, yes I need to use AD FS

Comment: I looked at pass-through. It looks interesting and could potentially work for us. Will I need to do changes on the web app?

Comment: No - if your app. uses OpenID Connect that is the standard for Azure.

Answer (score 1):

To connect the web app to ADFS, you could try to use the **scripted setup** for automated integration or use the **manual setup** to step-by-step.
For the details, you could refer to [the docs](https://auth0.com/docs/connections/enterprise/adfs#2-creates-rules-to-output-common-attributes).

Hope this can help you.

Comment: Thank you, will I need to do changes on my web app or is there a way around?